# p vs puts in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Is there any difference between `p` and `puts` in Ruby?

Answer (score 356, accepted):

`p foo` prints `foo.inspect` followed by a newline, i.e. it prints the value of `inspect` instead of `to_s`, which is more suitable for debugging (because you can e.g. tell the difference between `1`, `"1"` and `"2\b1"`, which you can't when printing without `inspect`).

Comment: Yep, p (and puts) are both in the Kernel module so you can see the details here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005961

Comment: Note that `p` also returns the value of the object, while `puts` does not.
`1.9.3p125 :002 > (p "foo").class "foo" => String 1.9.3p125 :003 > (puts "foo").class foo => NilClass`

Comment: Great summary provided by Gareth Rees in his post entitled ["Ruby p vs puts vs print"](http://www.garethrees.co.uk/2013/05/04/p-vs-puts-vs-print-in-ruby/).

Comment: Kinda feel like this leaves me with a rabbit hole of questions.
Whats inspect?
Whats to_s?
Why do I want to inspect printed text instead of a variable?
Which is more standard for the world of programming, due to your mention of debugging, p or puts?
Should all "p" be replaced with "puts" upon completion of debugging??

I see, in an above comment, that p returns an object, which is a huge difference. Im not sure if this answer is complete if it only mentions a small difference that will lead to bigger questions that still kind of answer the original question.

Comment: @AaronLoften `to_s` is the standard to-string method in Ruby. `inspect`. as I said, is an alternative to-string method, which produces an output more suitable for debugging. Upon completion of debugging you should obviously remove your debugging statements (or for more serious projects you should probably use a logging framework and not use p or puts for debugging at all). The fact that `p` returns the object seems irrelevant in most situations (and I believe I gave this answer before this was the case). The difference in output is the main difference (and used to be the only one).

Comment: Unless `foo` is an array, then `puts` prints `to_s` for each element on a separate line rather than `foo.to_s`.

Answer (score 56):

It is also important to note that `puts` "reacts" to a class that has `to_s` defined, `p` does not. For example:

```
class T
   def initialize(i)
      @i = i
   end
   def to_s
      @i.to_s
   end
end

t = T.new 42
puts t   => 42
p t      => #<T:0xb7ecc8b0 @i=42>
```

This follows directly from the `.inspect` call, but is not obvious in practice.

Answer (score 40):

`p foo` is the same as `puts foo.inspect`

Comment: but `puts` returns `nil`, instead of  `foo` as does `p`.

Comment: That's wrong. It's the same as `puts foo.inspect; foo`

Comment: This proves that you're answer is incorrect: `(-> {p "Hello World"}.call) == (-> {puts "Hello World".inspect}.call )
`.  Many upvotes does NOT make this a good answer!

Answer (score 5):

From [ruby-2.4.1 document](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/IO.html#method-i-puts)

## puts

> **`puts(obj, ...) → nil`**
>
> Writes the given object(s) to ios. Writes a **newline** after any that
>   do **not already** end with a newline sequence. **Returns nil**.
>
> The stream must be opened for writing. If called with an **array**
>   argument, writes **each element** on a new line. Each given object
>   that isn’t a string or array will be converted by calling its `to_s`
>   method. If called without arguments, outputs a single newline.

let's try it on irb

```
# always newline in the end 
>> puts # no arguments

=> nil # return nil and writes a newline
>> puts "sss\nsss\n" # newline in string
sss
sss
=> nil
>> puts "sss\nsss" # no newline in string
sss
sss
=> nil

# for multiple arguments and array
>> puts "a", "b"
a
b
=> nil
>> puts "a", "b", ["c", "d"]
a
b
c
d
=> nil
```

## p

> **`p(obj) → obj click to toggle source`**
>   **`p(obj1, obj2, ...) → [obj, ...]`**
>   **`p() → nil`**
>   For each object, directly writes `obj.inspect` followed by a newline to the program’s standard output.

in irb

```
# no arguments
>> p
=> nil # return nil, writes nothing
# one arguments
>> p "sss\nsss\n" 
"sss\nsss\n"
=> "aaa\naaa\n"
# multiple arguments and array
>> p "a", "b"
"a"
"b"
=> ["a", "b"] # return a array
>> p "a", "b", ["c", "d"]
"a"
"b"
["c", "d"]
=> ["a", "b", ["c", "d"]] # return a nested array
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the above answers, there is a subtle difference in console output - namely the presence/absence of inverted commas/quotation marks - that can be useful:

```
p "+++++"
>> "+++++"

puts "====="
>> =====
```

I find this useful if you want to make a simple progress bar, using the their close relative, **print**:

```
array = [lots of objects to be processed]
array.size
>> 20
```

This gives the 100% progress bar:

```
puts "*" * array.size
>> ********************
```

And this adds an incremental * on each iteration:

```
array.each do |obj|
   print "*"
   obj.some_long_executing_process
end

# This increments nicely to give the dev some indication of progress / time until completion
>> ******
```

Answer (score 0):

These 2 are equal:

```
p "Hello World"  
puts "Hello World".inspect
```

(**inspect** gives a more literal view of the object compared to **to_s** method)

Comment: they seem equal, but they are NOT.  Try it: `(->{p "Hello World"}.call) == (-> {puts "Hello World".inspect}.call )
`

Answer (score 0):

This may illustrate one of the key differences which is that `p` returns the value of what is passed to it, where as `puts` returns `nil`.

```
def foo_puts
  arr = ['foo', 'bar']
  puts arr
end

def foo_p
  arr = ['foo', 'bar']
  p arr
end

a = foo_puts
=>nil
a
=>nil

b = foo_p
=>['foo', 'bar']
b
['foo', 'bar']
```

Benchmark shows `puts` is slower

```
require 'benchmark'
str = [*'a'..'z']
str = str*100
res = Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report(:a) { 10.times {p str} }
  x.report(:b) { 10.times {puts str} }
end
puts "#{"\n"*10}"
puts res

0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.047310)
0.140000   0.090000   0.230000 (  0.318393)
```

Answer (score 0):

`p` method will print more extensive debuggable message, where `puts` will prettify message code.

e.g see below lines of code:

```
msg = "hey, Use \#{ to interpolate expressions"
puts msg #clean msg
p msg #shows \ with #
```

output will be

```
hey, Use #{ to interpolate expressions
"hey, Use \#{ to interpolate expressions"
```

[see output pic for more clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCbbR.png)