# getting round the ruby api

Tags: ruby

I'm having some trouble navigating the RDoc information at ruby-doc. Now it's probably just me, coming from the java world but am I missing something?

For instance when I want to do File IO, I look for File and find the respective page. There I see all the static methods on `File`. That's perfect. What I don't find here is the actual instance methods like `fileInstance.read_line`,  I actually found those by doing a puts of `fileInstance.methods`

I'd like to optimize my workflow, I'm sure I'll be delving into the ruby api a lot in the coming weeks, so have I just missed something here? Where would I find an example of read_line in the api?

Thanks

Comment: You might find [railsapi.com](http://railsapi.com/doc/ruby-v1.9.2/) useful. Personally I find the Ruby (and Rails) "official documentation sites" clunky.

Comment: Yup! railsapi.com uses SDOC (or Searchable rDOC). rubydoc.info has the same functionality (with YARD), but railsapi.com allows you to search methods and classes at the same time. The downfall is you cannot search project's SDOC individually going back to the main page, clicking "build your custom package", and selecting the (limited) amount of libraries to search from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/frames.

Also, a nice way of printing things like `my_instance.methods.sort` would be:

```
# Require the pp library...
# which just breaks long outputs into multiple lines.
require 'pp'

pp Object.new.methods.sort
```

Much easier on the eyes.

Other small tips:

- We use underscores_for_methods_and_vars, not camelCase.
- `p` and `puts` are different. See: [p vs puts in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255324/p-vs-puts-in-ruby)

Happy coding!

Comment: Great there it clearly shows read_lines as Methods inherited from IO, thank you

Comment: YARD is so much better than rdoc. I never understood why rdoc couldn't include the methods from mixins and parent classes.

Comment: I wouldn't lose sleep if they added YARD to the stdlib.