# Understanding Ruby symbol as method call

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9

```
class A
   def test
       "Test from instance"
   end
   class << self
       def test
           "Test from class"
       end
    end
end

p A.send(:test)    # "Test from class"
p A.new.method(:test).call  # "Test from instance"
```

Here symbol works as expected, but here:

```
s="test"
s1=:s
p s1   # :s
```

why **:s** is printed here?? I dont understand the reason behind it.
Can anyone please explain for me ?

Answer (score 18):

Symbols are sort of lightweight strings (though they are not strings). The `send()` and `method()` methods can take strings or symbols; one is converted to the other in the inner workings (not sure which) and then ruby executes the method with the matching name. Hence `A.send(:text)` is equivalent to `A.text()`. If you had a variable named `methodName = :text`, you could do `A.send(methodName)` but not `A.methodName()`.

Symbols are not variables, so you can't assign a value to a symbol. In your example, the symbol `:s` is unrelated to the variable `s` (despite the fact that they have the same "name", preceding it with a colon makes it a symbol instead of a variable). You're assigning a string value to the variable `s` but telling it to print the symbol `:s`, which it does.

Answer (score 4):

Symbols are just a special kind of stringlike value that's more efficient for the runtime to deal with than a regular string. That's it. They aren't methods or variables or anything like that.

When you do `A.send(:test)`, all you are doing is saying "hey, A, call the method named 'test'". You aren't sending the method itself, just the name; it's the logic inside `send` that is responsible for looking up the actual method to call.

The same thing goes when you ask for method with `A.new.method(:test)`.  All you are passing to `method` is the name "test", not the method defined with that name.  It's up to `method` to use the name and *find* the actual method so it can return it, and it's that return value - a Method object - that you are doing `call` on.  You can't do `call` on a Symbol like `:test`, because it's just a name.

Answer (score 3):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/1255362/509710:

`p foo` does puts `foo.inspect`, i.e. it prints the value of `inspect` instead of `to_s`, which is more suitable for debugging (because you can e.g. tell the difference between `1`, `"1"` and `"2\b1"`, which you can't when printing without inspect).

Comment: Hey I get it now...it was silly of me, I dint know the difference between p and puts. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
s="test"
s1=:s
p :s.object_id  #137448
p s.object_id   #77489950
p s1.object_id  #137448
```

I have understand it now.  I was assigning a symbol but expecting a string.

Answer (score 2):

You set the value of s1 to be :s, so why would you expect it to return anything different?

If you look at the ruby API for the Object class, you will see both [Object#send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send) and [Object#method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-method) take a symbol as a parameter, so the top example is also totally expected.