# How can I call a class method in Ruby with the method name stored in an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

I am currently working on a Poker game in Ruby. Instead of using numerous if-else statements to check the value of the player's hand, I decided to do the following:

```
  #calculate the players score
  def score
    POSS.map {|check|
      if (check[1].call())
        @score = check[0]
        puts @score
        return check[0]
      else
        false
      end
    }
  end

      POSS = [
    [10, :royal_flush?],
    [9, :straight_flush?],
    [8, :four_kind?],
    [7, :full_house?],
    [6, :flush?],
    [5, :straight?],
    [4, :three_kind?],
    [3, :two_pairs?],
    [2, :pair?]
  ]
```

The second item in each item of 'POSS' is a method I created to check whether the player has that hand. I am attempting to call the method with .call(), but get the following error:

```
Player.rb:43:in `block in score': undefined method `call' for 
:royal_flush?:Symbol (NoMethodError)    from Player.rb:42:in `map'  from
Player.rb:42:in `score'     from Player.rb:102:in `get_score'   from
Player.rb:242:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html `Object#send` is the method you are looking for.

Since you are wanting a 'class method', then Object should be self when declaring instance methods of the class that contains the 'class methods'

Try this code

```
 #calculate the players score
  def score
    POSS.map do |check|
      if self.send check[1] 
        @score = check[0]
        puts @score
        return check[0]
      else
        false
      end
    end
  end

      POSS = [
    [10, :royal_flush?],
    [9, :straight_flush?],
    [8, :four_kind?],
    [7, :full_house?],
    [6, :flush?],
    [5, :straight?],
    [4, :three_kind?],
    [3, :two_pairs?],
    [2, :pair?]
  ]
```

Styles vary from person to person, however, I think when using multi line blocks, it would be best to use 'do,end' pair instead of '{ }'

https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide

I think some confusion may come from code that looks like this

```
foobar = ->(foo,bar){puts "Passed in #{foo}, #{bar}"}
foobar.call("one","two")
```

If the first line was abstracted into other parts of the program you may have thought that foobar was a method, but its really a lambda. Procs and Lambdas are just like methods but better.. in their own way.. Check out this article on Procs, Blocks and Lambdas.

http://www.reactive.io/tips/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/

But also if interested check out https://www.codecademy.com/forums/ruby-beginner-en-L3ZCI for more detailed hands on with PBLS

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! And thank you for your suggestion and links, I will definitely check those out!

Answer (score 0):

No method is no method; and there is *no* `Symbol#call` which causes the immediate error.

The (or rather, *a*) way to call is via [`Object#__send__`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-send), supplying the name and arguments. One could also resolve a method and then call that; but `__send__` is the most direct route as Ruby is based on [message passing](http://www.integralist.co.uk/posts/message-passing.html).

That is, instead of `symbol.call(..)`, use `obj.__send__(symbol, ..)`. (In this case the object would probably be `self`.)

See [Understanding Ruby symbol as method call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736452/understanding-ruby-symbol-as-method-call)

Comment: It continues to give me the same error. I have royal_flush? defined earlier and it works when tested individually. Here is what my call looks like with your suggested changes: POSS.map {|check|
      if (Player.send check[1])

Comment: @PowerProject No method is no method. If it gives the same error (it will be the same *type* of error, but for a different receiver object and method name) then see previous. A method named `x` has to be present on `obj` when using `obj.__send__(:x)`. In this case you probably don't want to use `Player` (a class), but rather a *particular* player instance. If you do want to use a class, make sure that *class methods* are used.

Comment: The problem was that I was doing Player.send instead of self.send as mentioned by @Schylar

Comment: @PowerProject See the relevant linked documentation. Such is how `__send__` works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `send`.

```
class Foo
  def self.bar
    "bar"
  end

  def baz
    "baz"
  end
end

Foo.send(:bar) # => "bar"
f = Foo.new
f.send(:baz) # => "baz"
```

Though I'm not sure this is the best approach for the app you're writing.  When you get it working you can post it on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).