# How do I return JSON in the proper format in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

When I try to return JSON in the format shown above, my JSON looks like this

```
result = JSON.parse(data)
p result.to_json

#json from .to_json
\"is_claimed\": true,
\"rating\": 3.5,
\"mobile_url\": \"http: //m.yelp.com/biz/rudys-barbershop-seattle\",
...
```

When I use "p result" instead (without .to_json), I get the below:

```
"is_claimed"=>true,
"rating"=>3.5,
"mobile_url"=>"http://m.yelp.com/biz/rudys-barbershop-seattle",
....
```

The first has a '\' character and the second uses a hash rocket.  How do I return JSON in a normal format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format you're seeing is because of the way `p` outputs information, try changing your output to `puts`.

```
data = '{
  "is_claimed":true,
  "rating":3.5,
  "mobile_url":"http://m.yelp.com/biz/rudys-barbershop-seattle"
}'
result = JSON.parse(data)
puts result.to_json
```

EDIT: Some additional information on `p` vs `puts`: [p vs puts in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255324/p-vs-puts-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using `p` to display the contents of a `string`.

```
p "hi\"there"
"hi\"there"
=> "hi\"there"
[2] pry(main)> puts "hi\"there"
hi"there
```

Also, you should probably be aware of the difference between the methods `as_json` and `to_json`, see http://jonathanjulian.com/2010/04/rails-to_json-or-as_json/ to understand the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "normal format", I sometimes puts it out by

```
puts JSON.generate(result)
```

to get it in a friendly format.