# extra escape character appearing when using Ruby's p method to print string

Tags: ruby, string

I am attempting to write a simple function to perform string interpolation on arbitrary text in ruby. I also want the function to not evaluate escaped interpolation blocks so that "\#{foo}" would be converted to "#{foo}" rather than evaluated.

When I pass an expression with an escaped block, the value appears correct when I use the `puts` method, but includes the escape character when I use `p`. I don't understand why.

Here is my code:

```rb
def evil_mark text
  part = text.partition(/[^\\]\#{.*?}/)
  return_string = part[0]
  until part[1] == ""
     return_string << eval("\"" + part[1] + "\"")
     part = evil_mark(part[2]).partition(/[^\\]\#{.*?}/)
     return_string << part[0]
  end
  return_string.gsub!(/\\\#{.*?}/){|s| s[1..-1]}
  return return_string
end

$foo = 'faz'
$bar = 'baz'

s = 'This is some \#{$foo} bar and some #{$bar} bat'

puts evil_mark s
#~> This is some #{$foo} bar and some baz bat

p evil_mark s
#~> "This is some \#{$foo} bar and some baz bat"
```

By the way, I understand that it can be dangerous to use the `eval` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [p vs puts in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255324/p-vs-puts-in-ruby), which says that `p foo` is not actually shorthand for `puts foo` but for `puts foo.inspect`.  The value of `some_object.inspect` is going to show you the internals of the object, which are usually not the same as the string representation of the object.  For example:

```
irb(main):004:0> "hello".inspect
=> "\"hello\""
irb(main):006:0> p "hello"
"hello"
=> "hello"
irb(main):005:0> puts "hello"
hello
=> nil
```

Notice how `p` includes the quotes the same way that `inspect` does (though `inspect` shows them suitably escaped), while `puts` does not?

The major difference is that `inspect` will always show the internals of the object, while `puts` will call `to_s` (if it exists, otherwise there is a default `to_s` that is used).

Comment: Thanks, Moshe. Good explanation. I hadn't understood this distinction until this "problem" arose.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is wrong with the return. The only reason it still appears escaped when using #p is that p prints the string is such a way as that it could essentially be used directly as ruby code for that string. - that is to say #p adds the escape back in on purpose.

Comment: Ah! I see! Seems so obvious now. Thanks!