# How do I iterate through a nested array without flattening its contents?

Tags: ruby, arrays, enumerator

I have an array with pairs of numbers:

```
a = [[4, 6], [3, 0], [0, 0]]
```

When I do:

```
a.each do |x|
  puts x
done
```

I get a flattened set of values:

```
4
6
3
0
0
0
```

What I want is for the values to remain in pairs:

```
[4,6]
[3,0]
[0,0]
```

Ideally, I'd like to iterate with an `Enumerator`, because I'd like to make use of `#peek` during the loop processing.

I've found that:

```
e = a.each
loop do
  puts e.next
end
```

gives the same output as the flattened example above, with an additional `nil` at the end.

Is there a way to loop while preserve the grouping of the array in pairs?

Comment: As Arup's answer says, you _are_ getting the grouping in pairs already, but `puts` will print the array elements on separate lines. Try `puts a` and see what you get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use `p`, rather `puts`. Read this [`p` vs `puts`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255324/p-vs-puts-in-ruby).

`Kernel#puts` just treats arrays as a special case. It loops over the items and prints one per line. I didn't read *source*, that's just my understanding. I just confirmed from [source](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/io.c#6813), and found my understanding is correct :-

```
 io_puts_ary(VALUE ary, VALUE out, int recur)
6814 {
6815     VALUE tmp;
6816     long i;
6817 
6818     if (recur) {
6819         tmp = rb_str_new2("[...]");
6820         rb_io_puts(1, &tmp, out);
6821         return Qtrue;
6822     }
6823     ary = rb_check_array_type(ary);
6824     if (NIL_P(ary)) return Qfalse;
6825     for (i=0; i<RARRAY_LEN(ary); i++) {
6826         tmp = RARRAY_AREF(ary, i);
6827         rb_io_puts(1, &tmp, out);
6828     }
6829     return Qtrue;
6830 }
```

[`rb_io_puts`](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/io.c#6853) says -

> Writes the given objects to *ios* as with `IO#print`. Writes a record separator (typically a newline) after any that do not already end with a newline sequence.If called with an array argument, writes each element on a new line.If called without arguments, outputs a single record separator.

Comment: Thank you, I think that got me over the hump!