# How to change the amount a for loop increments in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, loops, for-loop, increment

Python Equivalent:

```
>>> for i in range(0, 9, 3):
>>>    print(i)
0
3
6
9
```

How can this be replicated in Ruby?

What would be the most Ruby-ish way to preform this operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use [step](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Range.html#method-i-step)

```
(0..9).step(3) do |i|
  puts i
end
```

Comment: Not that it is such a big of a problem, but I would recommend using "p" instead of "puts". it basically does the same job, but in my experience(not that big :) :D ), "puts" sometimes hides things like quotes sign and etc. Other than that the answer is correct.

Comment: Don't use `p` in production code. `p` is `inspect`-like, which doesn't return the same information as `puts` and can return very different output. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1255362/128421 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/1255362/128421.

Comment: When "debugging", yes. For production, no. Inspect output can vary wildly from the normal `puts` if `inspect` is implemented for that object.