# Why do `p` and `puts` give the same output? Are both calling `to_s`?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9

In the following code, `p` and `puts` give the same output.

```
class Book
  def initialize(title, price)
    @title = title
    @price = price
  end  
  def to_s
    "book with title=#{@title} and price=#{@price}"
  end
end

book1 = Book.new("Book of Ruby", 50.63)
puts book1 # => book with title=Book of Ruby and price=50.63
p book1    # => book with title=Book of Ruby and price=50.63
```

Why is this the case? `p` should have called `book1.inspect` instead of `book1.to_s`.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior your describe.  Ruby 2.2.3 behaves as expected with `p` doing `inspect` and `puts` doing `to_s`.  (I had to uncomment the `to_s` implementation though...)

Comment: I am using ruby 1.9.3

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255324/p-vs-puts-in-ruby

Comment: @Abs that link doesn't really provide any sort of answer to this question

Comment: I have accidentally flagged this one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ruby 1.9, the default behavior of `inspect` is to call `to_s`. This changed in later versions. You might have to override `inspect` as well as `to_s` if you want different output, or just upgrade your ruby version.

See here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-inspect

> If not overridden, uses the to_s method to generate the string.