# Ruby sometimes prints unicode-escaped chars instead of the chars themselves. Why?

Tags: ruby, puts

I use ruby 2.2.3p173, and Sublime 3. All my string already on encode('utf-8'). In Linux I have, what I expect. Try make output:

```
a = [ "Привет" ]
puts "puts=#{a}"
p "p=#{a}"
print "print=#{a}\n"

puts a[ 0 ]
p a[ 0 ]
print a[ 0 ] + "\n"
p a[ 0 ].encoding
p __ENCODING__
```

Output is:

```
puts=["\u041F\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442"]
"p=[\"\\u041F\\u0440\\u0438\\u0432\\u0435\\u0442\"]"
print=["\u041F\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442"]
Привет
"\u041F\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442"
Привет
#<Encoding:UTF-8>
#<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

I expect:

```
puts=["Привет"]
"p=[\"Привет\"]"
print=["Привет"]
Привет
"Привет"
Привет
```

How I can print Array with several "utf-8" string in one line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This is particularly observed on Windows.  On other *nix systems, it may work alright - For instance, on https://repl.it/ you see right output, as it is most likely hosted on a *nix system.*

As per documentation, [`Array#to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-to_s) is

> Alias for: inspect

`Array#inspect` invokes `inspect` on each of the array member, in this case, array members are all strings, thus `String#inspect` will be invoked.

`String#inspect` uses [`Encoding#default_external` as specified in documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Encoding.html#method-c-default_external) for inspection results.

> The default external encoding is used by default for strings created
>   from the following locations:
>
> - CSV
> - File data read from disk
> - SDBM
> - StringIO
> - Zlib::GzipReader
> - Zlib::GzipWriter
> - String#inspect
> - Regexp#inspect

On Windows, default external encoding is not UTF-8, and hence, we see the escaped sequences in output of `String#inspect`.

```
p Encoding::default_external
#=> #<Encoding:IBM437>
```

We change the default external encoding to UTF-8, output will be proper:

```
Encoding::default_external = Encoding::UTF_8

a = [ "Привет" ]
puts "puts=#{a}"
#=> puts=["Привет"]

p "p=#{a}"
#=> "p=[\"Привет\"]"
```

Comment: No, it does not explain that. I see his expected output, with both `puts` and `p`. Must be something wrong with his env, not his ruby.

Comment: I see the output what OP is seeing, I use plain .rb file to test and run using `ruby file.rb`

Comment: Granted, I tried on osx. But still it's not ruby's fault, I think

Answer (score 0):

Just try with **`irb console`** Or **`rails console`** .

It should be work.

[image]

**Note:** [Kindly check also difference between p and puts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255324/p-vs-puts-in-ruby)

Hope this answer help you !!!