# Ruby code explanation

Tags: ruby

I found following code at the internet

```
class Test
  def value
    'string'
  end

  def inspect
    'value'
  end
end

def test(arg)
  arg.tap { |i| i.value }
end

p test(Test.new)
```

Could anyone explain why it returns

```
p test(Test.new) 
# >> value
```

Comment: It's because method `test` ultimately returns `Test` instance, on which method `inspect` is called (internally, by Ruby console) to display it on the screen.

Comment: "returns" or "prints"? Big difference. This code __returns__ a `Test`, but it __prints__ string `"value"`.

Comment: FYI: this site is not a board of weird questions.

Comment: Please, read "[How to handle “Explain how this ${code dump} works” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253896/2988)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `arg.tap` returns  `arg` itself, and `p` prints  `arg.inspect`, since you have overwritten the`inspect` method of `Test`, it returns a string `'value'`, so you the print result is *value*

see also:
- [p vs puts in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255324/p-vs-puts-in-ruby)
 - [tap method](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/tap)

Answer (score 1):

tap used for chain of methods. It runs the passed blocked and returns the input without any change.

It means

`arg.tap { |i| i.value }` will return `arg`

`p` method runs `inspect` method of passed object