# How to remove a string from an array with Ruby 2.5.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I develop on Ruby on Rails 5.2.
With the purpose of managing translations, I wish to allow the user to select a language which is different from his current language. The list of configured languages of the application is

```
 all_languages = I18n.config.available_locales
```

all_languages is an Array. `puts all_languages` returns:

```
en fr de it
```

The user language is defined in the users table. A method returns current user's language

```
user_language = current_user.language
```

user_language is a String. `puts user_language` returns:

```
en
```

I try to apply the delete(obj) method to the array, but this does not alter the array:

```
all_languages.delete(user_language)
```

I try to work on arrays only, still it does not alter the languages array:

```
remove_language = Array.new
remove_language << user_language
```

`puts remove_language` returns:

```
en
```

`puts all_languages - remove_language` returns:

```
en fr de it
```

where the **en** language should be removed. I don't understand why it remains in the list!

Comment: Use `p` instead of `puts`, which will show the object in more detail. `puts` removes information such as whether you have a bare item or an array that includes it, as well as whether you have a string or a symbol.

Comment: I'm not understanding why your last attempt using `array - array` isn't working. Check my answer. Try it `rails console`.

Comment: @Jurgen string vs symbol

Comment: _"user_language is a String"_ – consider turning that into a symbol.

Comment: @Stefan: presumably, it comes from a database.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev sure, but `current_user.language` is a method call. You could override `language` or maybe have the ORM convert it. The code becomes easier if you are dealing with the correct "type" right from the start.

Comment: I can suggest to use `p` instead of `puts` for debugging or append `.inspect`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255324/p-vs-puts-in-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work, because `available_locales` returns an array of *symbols* and you are attempting to remove a *string*.

```
a = [:en, :fr, :de, :it]
a.delete('en')
#=> nil

a #=> [:en, :fr, :de, :it]
```

To fix this, you have to turn your string into a symbol. Furthermore, you should avoid `delete` because it modifies the receiver (modifying `available_locales` might result in bugs later on). You can use Rails' [`Array#without`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-without) instead which returns a new array:

```
all_languages = I18n.config.available_locales
#=> [:en, :fr, :de, :it]

user_language = current_user.language.to_sym
#=> :en

all_languages.without(user_language)
#=> [:fr, :de, :it]
```

Comment: Thank you all! I finally took the solution of Johan Wentholt to convert to an array of strings and use it .without(user_language).

Answer (score 7):

`I18n.config.available_locales` returns symbols *. And your `current_user.language` is a string. `"en"` is not at all the same thing as `:en`. That said, this should work:

```
all_languages = I18n.config.available_locales.dup # copy the array
all_languages.delete(:en)
# or, for your case
all_languages.delete(current_user.language.to_sym)


# non-mutating way
all_langs_without_en = I18n.config.available_locales.reject { |loc| loc == :en }
```

---

<sub>* at least in rails 4.2, where I checked this.</sub>

Comment: @Jurgen: thanks, but sawa called it 50 mins ago, and nobody listened :)

Comment: Alternatively you could change the available locales into strings instead of changing to user language into a symbol. `all_languages = I18n.config.available_locales.map(&:to_s)`

Comment: @Stefan: why did I think it was duping the array? :facepalm:

Comment: It probably depends on the backend being used, but unless the API guarantees it, `dup` is the safer choice. BTW, in Rails there's also [`Array#without`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-without).

Comment: @Stefan: ah, Array#without. I was wondering why something like that doesn't exist. Post that as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
all_languages = ["en","fr","de","it"]
user_language = "en"
all_languages.delete_at(all_languages.index(user_language))

#=> ["fr","de","it"]
```

Comment: The delete should have worked. What makes it fail, will prevent this one from working too.

Comment: I believe delete is not working because of conflict with active record delete method. Is it possible?

Comment: No, that is not what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

This solution should meet your need:

```
l = I18n.config.available_locales
l.pop
I18n.config.available_locales = l
```

Comment: op wants to remove the user's selected language, your method doesn't guarantee you're removing the right item in the array.

Comment: This is just an example, and if you want to remove the specific item, you could use `delete` method to get the desired array and then assign it to `I18n.config.available_locales`