# How to get a string with `"\y"`

Tags: ruby, string, escaping, literals

I have a password that contains `"\y"`. I get:

```
"a\yb" # => "ayb"
'a\yb' # => 'a\\yb'
"a\\yb" # => "a\\yb"
'a\\b' # => "a\\yb"
```

And nothing (like `concatenation` or `sub`) works.

Is there a way to not change the password?

Comment: It is unclear what your question is. Can you show a piece of code that you are trying to use and is failing?

Comment: I read the password from the secrets and it did not work. I try simple string and have behavior like in question

Comment: for example ruby -e 'puts "a\\yb"' => "ayb"

Comment: I have your version of ruby and get `a\yb` as output on the terminal. Please post exactly what you are running and is not working so we can better understand.

Comment: After your edits, `p` is the problem. Use `puts` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say:

```
'a\yb'
```

Then you get this back:

```
"a\\yb"
```

These are **identical** as far as Ruby is concerned. Inside of double quotes (`"`) the backslash has special meaning. A single backslash is used to indicate either control codes like `\n` meaning newline, or literal versions of same, like `\\` meaning *literal* backslash.

Try this:

```
puts "a\\yb"
```

Then you'll see exactly what you want. The `\\` part is just escaping.

When you use `p` you're calling:

```
puts "a\\yb".inspect
```

This `inspect` part puts it back into a double-quoted and escaped string, which is where you're getting confused. Print the string, not the "inspected" version of it.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me. Can you show us some context?

```
ruby -v
#=> ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x86_64-linux]
ruby -e 'puts "a\\yb"'
#=> a\yb
```

After your edits, the problem is using `p` instead of `puts`. For instance:

```
ruby -e 'puts "a\\yb"'
#=> a\yb
ruby -e 'p "a\\yb"'
#=> "a\\yb"
```

See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255324/p-vs-puts-in-ruby).

Comment: ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859)

Answer (score 0):

In simple words `p` print `obj.inspect` to output

Simple way to see this:

```
irb(main):009:0> string = %q{a\yb}
=> "a\\yb"

irb(main):018:0> puts string.inspect
"a\\yb"

irb(main):019:0> p string
"a\\yb"

irb(main):010:0> puts string
a\yb
```