# Garbage Base64 decoded string

Tags: ruby, linux, encryption, base64

Could somebody explain me, why there are two various outputs?

CODE IN IRB(Interactive ruby shell):

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'base64'
=> true 
irb(main):002:0> cookie = "YXNkZmctLTBEAiAvi95NGgcgk1W0pyUKXFEo6IuEvdxhmrfLqNVpskDv5AIgVn8wfIWf0y41cb%2Bx9I0ah%2F4BIIeRJ54nX2qGcxw567Y%3D"
=> "YXNkZmctLTBEAiAvi95NGgcgk1W0pyUKXFEo6IuEvdxhmrfLqNVpskDv5AIgVn8wfIWf0y41cb%2Bx9I0ah%2F4BIIeRJ54nX2qGcxw567Y%3D" 
irb(main):003:0> decoded_cookie = Base64.urlsafe_decode64(URI.decode(cookie))
=> "asdfg--0D\x02 /\x8B\xDEM\x1A\a \x93U\xB4\xA7%\n\\Q(\xE8\x8B\x84\xBD\xDCa\x9A\xB7\xCB\xA8\xD5i\xB2@\xEF\xE4\x02 V\x7F0|\x85\x9F\xD3.5q\xBF\xB1\xF4\x8D\x1A\x87\xFE\x01 \x87\x91'\x9E'_j\x86s\x1C9\xEB\xB6"
```

Code from Linux terminal:

```
asd@asd:~# ruby script.rb
asdfg--0D /��M� �U��%
\Q(苄��a��˨�i�@�� V0|���.5q������ ��'�'_j�s9�
```

Script:

```
require 'base64'
require 'ecdsa'
cookie = "YXNkZmctLTBEAiAvi95NGgcgk1W0pyUKXFEo6IuEvdxhmrfLqNVpskDv5AIgVn8wfIWf0y41cb%2Bx9I0ah%2F4BIIeRJ54nX2qGcxw567Y%3D"

def decode_cookie(cookie)
  decoded_cookie = Base64.urlsafe_decode64(URI.decode(cookie))
end

puts (decode_cookie(cookie))
```

How can i get the same output in terminal?
I need the output:

> "asdfg--0D\x02 /\x8B\xDEM\x1A\a \x93U\xB4\xA7%\n\Q(\xE8\x8B\x84\xBD\xDCa\x9A\xB7\xCB\xA8\xD5i\xB2@\xEF\xE4\x02 V\x7F0|\x85\x9F\xD3.5q\xBF\xB1\xF4\x8D\x1A\x87\xFE\x01 \x87\x91'\x9E'_j\x86s\x1C9\xEB\xB6"

In Linux terminal.

Comment: You probably want to use `p` rather than `puts`. You'll find all the details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255324/p-vs-puts-in-ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A string like `"\x8B"` is a representation of character, not the literal `\x8B`. Ruby uses such representation if it's missing the font to display the character or if it messes with whitespacing (for example `"\n"` is a newline and not `\` followed by a `n`).

The reason you get another output in irb is because you don't print the string using `puts` (like you do in your script). Simply calling `decoded_cookie` will return the string representation, not the actual content.

You can display the actual content by simply printing it to an output.

```
require 'base64'

cookie = "YXNkZmctLTBEAiAvi95NGgcgk1W0pyUKXFEo6IuEvdxhmrfLqNVpskDv5AIgVn8wfIWf0y41cb%2Bx9I0ah%2F4BIIeRJ54nX2qGcxw567Y%3D"
decoded_cookie = Base64.urlsafe_decode64(URI.decode(cookie))
puts decoded_cookie
# asdfg--0D /��M �U��%
# \Q(苄��a��˨�i�@�� V0|���.5q����� ��'�'_j�s9�
#=> nil
```

You can find more info about the `"\xnn"` representation [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings).

If you'd like the script to display the string representation use `p` instead of `puts`, or use `puts decoded_cookie.inspect`.