# Print nothing using p() - Ruby

Tags: ruby, null, primes, conditional-operator

I'm stumbling on using a ternary with the p() function in ruby. My code is:

```
 p i.prime?? i:''
```

Problem is, when i is not prime, it displays quotes instead of displaying nothing.

How do I fix this and make it print nothing? I don't want to print whitespace either. just nothing.

Comment: `p i if i.prime?` maybe?

Comment: I want to use the ternary operator.

Comment: Since you mentioned code golf: note that the `if` variant is shorter here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the difference between `p` and `puts` here: [p vs puts in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255324/p-vs-puts-in-ruby)

For your question, sticking with the ternary, try just:

```
i.prime? ? (p i) : ''
```

Comment: Works perfectly. I'm trying a code golf problem, so I don't want to use puts.