# Sinatra: ERROR TypeError: no implicit conversion of Array into String

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I made a rather simple sinatra server that just prints the requests it gets to test how it works and I when I use it locally, it works fine. But when I put in in kubernetes it starts giving me this error:

```
10.1.38.202 - - [15/Apr/2021:13:09:44 +0000] "POST /api/v1/interact HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0010
[2021-04-15 13:09:44] ERROR TypeError: no implicit conversion of Array into String
        /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:120:in `block in service'
        /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/body_proxy.rb:41:in `each'
        /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/body_proxy.rb:41:in `method_missing'
        /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:119:in `service'
        /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
        /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
        /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/webrick/server.rb:307:in `block in start_thread'
10.1.14.163 - - [15/Apr/2021:13:09:44 UTC] "POST /api/v1/interact HTTP/1.1" 500 365
```

Here's the script:

```
# server.rb
require 'sinatra'
require "sinatra/namespace"

# sinatra config
set :port, 3141
set :bind, '0.0.0.0'

# Endpoints
get '/alive' do
  'Welcome to workstreams!'
end

namespace '/api/v1' do

  before do
    content_type 'application/json'
  end

  helpers do
    def json_params
      begin
        JSON.parse(request.body.read)
      rescue
        halt 400, { message: 'Invalid JSON' }.to_json
      end
    end
  end

  post '/interact' do
    p request
    request = json_params
    p request
  end

  post '/slash' do
    request = json_params
    p request
  end
end
```

And heres the requests im sending:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:3141/api/v1/interact' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "hello": "hi"
}'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [p vs puts in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255324/p-vs-puts-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Using **p** to print the request is what was causing the problem. I switched to **puts** and now it seamlessly.

I still don't understand why it work on once instance and no the other though.