# Is calling puts without arguments bad practice?

Tags: ruby, rubymine

Below is a small screenshot from within RubyMine 3.1. I am just starting to learn Ruby. The code here is from the Presenter-First MVP C# code generator over at [atomicobject.com](http://www.atomicobject.com/pages/Presenter+First).

I am using this project along with a book to learn Ruby. The [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/) for `puts` shows that it expects at least one parameter. Yet this code appears "somewhat legal" for two reasons:

1. The code appears to work fine when I
   step thru it via the debugger.
2. [Searching online](http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyfeatures/a/io.htm), and even [here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639810/how-to-add-extra-newline-with-puts-without-sticking-newline-character-into-stri/639817#639817), shows that `puts` w/o arguments creates a newline.

However, is it bad practice to do this (hence the RubyMine warning)? The code I am looking at is from 2006. I'm running it with Ruby 1.9.2 if that matters any.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is perfectly fine, as `puts` provides 'default' value for the first parameter:

```
def puts(obj='', *arg)
```

As for RubyMine, it doesn't show any errors for me. May it happen that you define method `puts` somewhere else in your code? You can <kbd>cmd</kbd>+click on it, to get to the definition.

Anyway, if you're able to reproduce problem in a clean new project, you can freely submit a bug report to JetBrains.

Comment: @Nikita Rybak, When I click "Go To Definition" I Get this: `def puts(obj, *smth)` in kernel.rb. This kernal.rb method is a stub for indexing and the comment at the top of the file says: "This is a machine generated stub using stdlib-doc for <b>module Kernel</b>
 Ruby sources used:  Ruby-1.9.1 p0
 Created on Wed Jun 17 12:55:08 +0400 2009 by IntelliJ Ruby Stubs Generator."

Comment: @Matt That's interesting... I do think there's a default assignment somewhere, as invoking methods without it (e.g., `print`) will make `nil` to appear for me.

Comment: @Matt If you have spare time, you can still open a ticket at jetbrains and see what they say.

Comment: @Nikita, I'll try to recreate the issue with an empty project, and if successful I'll open a ticket. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Nikita, They plan to fix this in 3.1.1: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RUBY-7846

Answer (score 1):

No, it can be helpful to create the physical line break in your source as well as the output, and like you have seen already, `puts` is perfectly capable of accepting zero arguments.

Personally, if I'm creating a multi-line output I prefer to use [here-doc syntax](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#here_doc).